# How to program the simple task of switching tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, switching

Here's an overview of my program:

Android 2.2

- MainActivity (tabhost)

4 Tabs

- Search (uses SearchActivity) (default)
- Artists (uses ArtistsActivity)
- Albums (uses AlbumsActivity)
- Songs (uses SongsActivity)

The app loads up to the default Search tab and SearchActivity. I can type in a search string and click search (this stores data in a global variables class). Now when I manually click on the Artists tab, it loads ArtistsActivity and the appropriate view and it grabs data from this global variables class and does stuff.

I can manually click on all tabs and switch between the tabs just fine.

However, if I use any type of setCurrentTab command to automatically switch to the next tab for the user, the program crashes with a null pointer exception.

I've tried multiple different methods I found online and not a single one of them worked.

The apps works completely fine with manually clicking tabs as a user. But I need to program this ability to happen automatically.

Example for what needs to happen automatically:
App Loads->SearchTab->User types in search string and clicks Search button->ArtistsTab

It doesn't make any sense. Why can't I program the ability to automatically switch to the next tab when I can manually switch to the next tab as a user by clicking on it? It already works just fine, I just need to replicate the action of clicking on these tabs within the code so the user doesn't have to manually click the next tab.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Post some code and the logcat

Comment: I got it worked out. Thanks. See below.

Answer (score 0):

declare your tabhost/tabwidget as static and call setcurrent tab accessing that static tabwidget from your activity 
    ex-

```
TabActivity.tabhost.setcurrentTab(1);
```

Comment: I had been trying that and receiving null pointer exception. I did find a solution though that I'll post below.

In the tab activity:

`TabHost tabHost =  (TabHost) getParent().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);`

In the OnClickListener:

`tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);`

It appears the getParent() before the findViewByID is necessary to fix this issue.

So I just declare a tabHost in each tab activity using that first line and am able to switch between tabs flawlessly.